# How do I update my jdk update 12 to jdk update <latest> without having to download the whole 100+MB jdk bunch?

Tags: java, updates, jdk

How does one update jdk update 12 to jdk update  without having to download the whole 100+MB jdk bunch?

OS: Fedora 9 (About to go Fedora 11, but that is a different story)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora or Sun doesn't provide incremental updates to the JDK, there's really no practical way to avoid the 100MB+ download.